# i have installed scilab latest version but it is showing error

Tags: scilab

i have installed scilab latest version but it is showing error but after install when i try to open `scilab` either from terminal or graphically it shows me this error...

> Scilab cannot create Scilab Java Main-Class (we have not been able to find the main Scilab class. Check if the Scilab and thirdparty packages are available).

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? How did you installed Scilab?

Comment: i have installed ubuntu 19.04.4 and i have installed scilab form terminal using  apt-get install scilab